# Why do my columns behave differently after upgrading to Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

If I execute the following in bootstrap 3, then everything works as expected. But it does not break correctly in bootstrap 4. Please execute the examples below, the first runs with BS4 then last with BS3.

I expect it to look like in **Bootstrap 3.3.6**.

```css
#orange_containers .row div {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="orange_containers" class="">

  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="icon">
          A
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="text">
          <h4>Test</h4>
          <p>
            I'm speaking with myself, number one, because I have a very good brain and I've said a lot of things. If Trump Ipsum weren’t my own words, perhaps I’d be dating it.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="icon">
          B
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="text">
          <h4>Test</h4>
          <p>
            The other thing with Lorem Ipsum is that you have to take out its family. We have so many things that we have to do better... and certainly ipsum is one of them. We are going to make placeholder text great again. Greater than ever before.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Bootstrap 4**

```css
#orange_containers .row div {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="orange_containers" class="">

  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="icon">
          A
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="text">
          <h4>Test</h4>
          <p>
            I'm speaking with myself, number one, because I have a very good brain and I've said a lot of things. If Trump Ipsum weren’t my own words, perhaps I’d be dating it.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="icon">
          B
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="text">
          <h4>Test</h4>
          <p>
            The other thing with Lorem Ipsum is that you have to take out its family. We have so many things that we have to do better... and certainly ipsum is one of them. We are going to make placeholder text great again. Greater than ever before.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Note: You have to view the result in fullscreen.

[Try Bootstrap 3 example in Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/i8pRUcI7nz)

[Try Bootstrap 4 Example in Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/CL6AQWfRcz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add a container and some rows. Also you can't have a col as a child of another col, it would need to be within a row. See here for details: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#nesting

Try changing your code to the following:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="orange_containers" class="">

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row no-gutters">

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="icon">
                            A
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h4>Test</h4>
                            <p>
                                I'm speaking with myself, number one, because I have a very good brain and I've said a lot of things. If Trump Ipsum weren’t my own words, perhaps I’d be dating it.
                            </p>
                            /div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="icon">
                            B
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h4>Test</h4>
                            <p>
                                The other thing with Lorem Ipsum is that you have to take out its family. We have so many things that we have to do better... and certainly ipsum is one of them. We are going to make placeholder text great again. Greater than ever before.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It also works without the container. I just had to add a row